# Seq2Seq Machine Translation Question

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, machine-translation

I'm reading through Pytorch's [NLP from Scratch: Translation with a Sequence to Sequence Network and Attention](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html), and I am a bit confused on the Preparing Training Data section, particularly:

```py
def indexesFromSentence(lang, sentence):
    return [lang.word2index[word] for word in sentence.split(' ')]


def tensorFromSentence(lang, sentence):
    indexes = indexesFromSentence(lang, sentence)
    indexes.append(EOS_token)
    return torch.tensor(indexes, dtype=torch.long, device=device).view(-1, 1)


def tensorsFromPair(pair):
    input_tensor = tensorFromSentence(input_lang, pair[0])
    target_tensor = tensorFromSentence(output_lang, pair[1])
    return (input_tensor, target_tensor)
```

Why do they add an EOS token to the end but not a SOS in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really important in the encoder, but it plays a crucial role in the decoder.

At the training time, you use the target sentence in the following way (with a 5-token sentence $w_1, \ldots, w_5$):

```
[BOS]  w₁   w₂   w₃   w₄   w₆
  ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│           DECODER           │
└─────────────────────────────┘
  ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓   
  w₁   w₂   w₃   w₄   w₅ [EOS]
```

This means, the decoder needs to be provided with the `[BOS]` token to generate the first real token. At inference time, you need to know when to stop generating new tokens. You stop when you generate the `[EOS]` token.